# PHP preg_match_all match the closest value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

My text is something like this:

```
[if-abc]content of abc[/if] [if-def]content of def[/if]
```

i want to match:

```
[if-abc]content of abc[/if] and then [if-def]content of def[/if]
```

but my current function matches the entire thing. how can i make it so it matches the first occurence of the closing [/if] tag

```
$m = null;
preg_match_all('/\[if-([a-z-]*)\](.*)\[\/if\]/', $source, $m);
```

This works except when multiple conditions are present on the same line.

Comment: Regular expression are not the right tool for this task. Parse the text instead.

Comment: it seems to be working just fine, whats the reason why i should parse?

Comment: Because sooner or later you will face problems, that you cannot resolve so easily and especially because you will forget things and introduce security issues. it's the same reason, why applying regular expressions on HTML is a bad idea (and so on ;)).

Comment: thanks for the thought, appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your star quantifier [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) with...

```
preg_match_all('/\[if-([a-z-]*)\](.*?)\[\/if\]/', $source, $m);
```

This way the `.*` construct will start matching from 'no symbols at all' state, gradually widening it, one symbol at a time - and will stop doing it when it encounters the *first* `[/if]` part in the string's flow. Otherwise it actually starts with consuming *all* the string, releasing one symbol at a time - and stops when it faces the *last* `[/if]` part in the string's flow.